# How to catch a rethrown exception?

Tags: c#, .net, error-handling

I have the following code:

```
try
{
    await _policyService.QueuePayment();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var slackError = new ErrorNotificationMessage("{ex.Message}");

    await Notify(slackError);
}
```

I want to give more detail and log it to Slack if the Exception is a Security Exception, so I extended this try/catch block as follows:

```
 try
{
    await _policyService.QueuePayment();
}
catch (SecurityException ex)
{
    throw new Exception("detailed message", ex);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     var slackError = new ErrorNotificationMessage("{ex.Message}");

     await Notify(slackError);
}
```

However this does not catch the rethrown Exception and log it to Slack. What am I missing here?

Comment: "*What am I missing here?*" -- `catch` statements catch exceptions thrown in the corresponding `try` block. An exception thrown in one `catch` block is not caught by subsequent `catch` blocks.

Comment: Thanks @canton7 - so I need to have 2 `try`s here?

Comment: Or refactor out the `Notify` logic -- it's currently just in the `catch (Exception ex)` block, and you're jumping through hoops to get all of your exceptions through that block. Move it out to a separate helper method, then `catch (SecurityException ex) { await NotifyError(new Exception("detailed message", ex); } catch (Exception ex) { await NotifyError(ex); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was already mentioned in comments by @canton7, you'd need a `try-catch` inside the `catch (SecurityException ex)` in order to catch it. However, as it was also mentioned, that doesn't make sense here. It's also not a common (or rather, correct) practice to wrap an exception just to change the error message.

Just use standard boolean logic:

```
try
{
    await _policyService.QueuePayment();               
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var message = ex is SecurityException ? "Some very important message" : ex.Message;
    var slackError = new ErrorNotificationMessage(message);
    await Notify(slackError);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> However this does not catch the rethrown Exception and log it to Slack. What am I missing here?

When we throw an exception explicitly it can be catched at the caller end by enclosing the method call in a try catch block. We cannot throw and catch the exception from a catch block in same method unless we add another try catch which does not actually make sense here.

What you should be doing is directly throwing that exception like :

```
try
 {
     await _policyService.QueuePayment();
            
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
      if(ex is SecurityException)
      {
          // for security exception do something different
      }
      else
      {
          var slackError = new ErrorNotificationMessage("{ex.Message}");

          await Notify(slackError);
      }

      
 }
```

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto right, i have updated post